# Using simple HTML in ContentChildren and converting to more complex html with a custom element in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to take the ContentChildren of a custom element to populate my template.

```
<my-element>
    <div #text>
        My Text
     </div>
    <div #anchor>
      <a href="">button</a>
    </div> 
 </my-element>
```

Then I'm  using @ContentChild to get the values

```
@ContentChild('text') public myText: ElementRef;
@ContentChild('anchor') public myanchor: ElementRef;
```

Then I'm trying to get these values to build my-element template.

```
myText = this.text.nativeElement.innerHTML;
myAnchorHref = this.anchor.nativeElement.getAttribute('href');
MyAnchorText = this.anchor.nativeElement.innerHTML;
```

Then in my template

```
<div [innerHtml]="myText"></div>
<a [href]="myAnchorHref" [textContent]="MyAnchorText"></a>
```

This is a simplified version of course, but what I'm trying to do if take very simple html and using a custom element turn it into something far more complex.

I know there's security risks with ElementRef so I would like to avoid it.

I tried using ng-content but in many cases I need to manipulate the data before adding to the template, like in the case of the anchor.

What I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this, this just doesn't feel right.